# How to always launch app on Gear vr USB attachment

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, gear-vr

An Android application for Gear VR using Samsung S6 and S7.
Following implementation is for auto launch on mobile insertion to VR.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
         android:name=".SplashActivity"
         android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
         android:launchMode="singleTask"
         android:excludeFromRecents="true"
         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
         android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
         android:screenOrientation="landscape"
         android:stateNotNeeded="true">

    <intent-filter>                    
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />

    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.proximity_sensor"          /> </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" /> </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" /> </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                        android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </activity>
```

device_filter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="04e8" product-id="07d2" /> 
</resources>
```

It works but there is problem with **Oculus** app, sometime my app launch before Oculus app and other time Oculus app appear but my app doesn't launch.

Sometime when our app is open before mounting to VR **Oculus** app crash saying "Unfortunately, Oculus Home has stopped." due to conflict and system shows dialog.

Comment: By simply putting this into your Empty activity you can experience the problem. Sometime Samsung s6 will show dialog with check box "Use by default for this USB device"

Comment: I thought the app had to be approved by the store before you could launch via Oculus app?

Comment: You right, We are in testing phase. To solve this problem I have write background service that start after device insertion broadcast and make sure our app is running. so user doesn't face much problem now.

Comment: What's the `product-id="07d2"` stands for?

Comment: @mosquetero it's Samsung Gear VR product id for USB identification

Comment: @Robert approval is not required. you need to [this](http://www.gearvrf.org/bin/view/GearVRfDeveloperGuide/GearVRfDevGuide200Start#SampleApps) way

Comment: @Qamar Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Qamar please I need to know how can I keep my app running? I face a problem each time I attach the device to the Gear vr USB, my activity is gone black and Oculus home is started. Once deacttached, it returns back to my app.

Answer (score 0):

Those docs are helpful :)
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

For example this is how we can get details about attached device.

```
UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
```